# Using Netbeans on local and git (client) on remote server

Tags: php, git, netbeans-8

I've a php application that runs on a remote server, Netbeans instead runs on a local machine (remote project).
This application is an open source software on which I want make some changes for private use, but I would also update the core regularly from the upstream git server and merge my changes.
Can I install git on the remote server and use it to fetch and pull the updates and use Netbeans from local to visualize the diffs? Or I have to install a web server and git on local machine to take advantage from Netbeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a web server on the local machine in any case. If you want to visualize the diffs within Netbeans then it needs to be working on a checked-out copy of the code. I can think of a few ways to do this, which is best depends on your workflow and whether or not the remote project is live.

- Checkout the files on the remote server and then mount that directory via a network share (like via SSHFS) so that Netbeans can work with the files as if they were local. Local changes will appear immediately on the remote server. Some people find this method too slow, your mileage may vary. Performance of working with remote files has increased a bunch from Netbeans 7.4 to 8.0. Your git commits and merges can be done from either machine.
- Checkout the files on the remote server. Checkout the files on the local machine. Develop locally with Netbeans. When you want to see your changes on the remote server, you'll have to commit them from the local machine and then pull them to the remote.
- Install (not checkout) the files on the remote server. (Like via git-archive.) Checkout the files on the local machine. Configure Netbeans to upload to the remote server on save. Develop locally with Netbeans. You'll have the diffs locally and instant remote changes. All your git work will be done from the local machine and if you screw up the remote, you can just wipe it out and do another git-archive to restore the latest version.